# Android - A View taking place but doesn't show up

Tags: android, layout, view

Here is the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/weightValueTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/weightDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/weightDifferenceTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/change_green"/>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_blue" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The view `weightLossIndicator` doesn't appear on device and simulator although it affects the other elements on the layout (their position). The background color is opaque and does appear in the Graphical Layout.

**Update:**
I tried to set a fixed height for the ImageView as 40 dp and guess what, it appears! Something wrong using `match_parent` but I don't know what. I also have to say, I am using this XML as `ListView` row layout.

Comment: What layout is the parent layout? Pls post the complete XML file. You can ideally assign a Id to the LinearLAyout and in the weightLossIndicator view you can mention android:layout_below this adjacent linearlayout.

Comment: Have you wrapped your current XML in a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper Yes, it is.

Comment: Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/weightLossIndicator"` from your `separator`. Add to the `weightLossIndicator` this attribute: `android:layout_above="@+id/separator"`

Comment: @SherifelKhatib didn't work either. Have just tried it.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? So that we can really visualize it? Oh and also add "alignPArenttop" to your weightLossIndicator

Comment: Tried that too! I have been working on it the last couple of days. I have a work around by making the parent layout has a background color assigned as weight loss indicator (and hence I removed the indicator). But still, I want to know why it doesn't appear.

Comment: If you check "Show layout bounds" in Settings > Developer options, do the bounds of your weightLossIndicator appear?

Answer (score 1):

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/change_green" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weightValueTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weightDateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weightDifferenceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Paste this in Relative layout it works :) .Please provide exact layout requirement in diagram

Comment: Just our of curiosity, what difference does it make than my XML?

Comment: references are changed

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/weightValueTextView"
        android:text="valueText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/weightDateTextView"
        android:text="dateText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/weightDifferenceTextView"
        android:text="differencetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:background="#00FF00"/>

<View 
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="#0000FF" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my issue was not directly related but your answer helped me.  Only my first two controls showed up -- I started thinking that the others were being rendered offscreen but couldn't prove it.  Anyways, I was missing android:orientation="vertical" on my main layout. I saw that in your example.  After I added it, everything showed up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the layout file (which misses the container layout BTW),I see that you want to achieve this:

AB
AB
AC

where A is the LinearLayout(doesn't have an id), B is the weightLossIndicator,and C is the separator.

is this correct?

if so, you should set C as aligning to the bottom right, and make B above it, and only then decide what to do with A.

also, if B still fails to take space, try using an ImageView instead .

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your WeightLossIndicator LinearLayout's `LayoutWeight` to `android:layout_weight="1"`

**Edit:**

Actually, I noticed you have a sibling view. Depending one how you want to layout your view (perhaps 50%/%50) then you can apply both the linearlayout and the ImageView to use `android:layout_weight="1"`

**Edit again**

As indicated in the comments,  This scenario would only apply to child layouts contained inside of a LinearLayout.

Comment: I believe it's effective if the parent layout is LinearLayout not a relative one

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something obvious, just copy&pasted your xml, assigned a text to the `TextViews`, and confirmed that `weightValueTextView` appears. Is something like this the result you're expecting? (ignore the color, I hardcoded its value)

[image: Layout screenshot]

I'm guessing you're programmatically setting the appropriate text values; a snippet from your `Activity` would be useful, just in case you're accidentally doing anything else you shouldn't.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I want. Still not working. But do you use it in a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightValueTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weightDifferenceTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/weightLossIndicator"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/change_green"/>
        <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/change_green" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, the separator will not take the whole width. In fact, it's recommended not to set a subview width to match_parent while its parent width is wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

I would try first using a different avd one with a big display. setvisible true is this attribute set false in the code? Relative layout is tricky and once you do get it looking good if you use another device it most likely won't appear how you want it. Also android:src ="@drawable/mypic" and make sure you have a pic in the drawable folders